# How do I go from a PostgreSQL native point type to a PostGIS point?

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, postgis, type-conversion

If I have a [`point`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-geometric.html)

```
SELECT point(long,lat);
```

How do I go from that to a PostGIS point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

This is no longer required there is now a native cast from gemoetry to native Point and vise-versa:

```sql
SELECT ST_MakePoint(0,0)::Point;
SELECT ST_AsText( Point(0,0)::geometry );
```

---

There is no implicit conversion or casting from a PostgreSQL native point type to a PostGIS geometry, and a PostGIS POINT has a Spatial Reference System attached to it. [ST_MakePoint](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html) will create the point geometry, but it'll be apart from any system that maps it to Earth,

```
SELECT ST_MakePoint(p[0],p[1])
FROM ( VALUES (point(-71.1043443253471,42.3150676015829)) ) AS t(p);
```

We're accessing the [point type with the array syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-geometry.html),

> It is possible to access the two component numbers of a point as though the point were an array with indexes 0 and 1. For example, if t.p is a point column then SELECT p[0] FROM t retrieves the X coordinate and UPDATE t SET p[1] = ... changes the Y coordinate. In the same way, a value of type box or lseg can be treated as an array of two point values.

Comment: you can wrap an ST_SetSRID around the ST_MakePoint and you'll have a proper coordinate system assigned to your geometry...