# Going from long/lat cords to Geometry or Geography type

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, cast

When I make a query:

```
select *, 
       concat(pickup_longitude,' ',pickup_latitude) as pickup_pt, 
       concat(dropoff_longitude,' ',dropoff_latitude) as dropoff_pt
```

it usually defines the `pickup_pt` and the `dropoff_pt` as datatype `text` from default apparently.

Is there a way to define the column in another datatype?

Perhaps something like:

```
concat(pickup_longitude,' ',pickup_latitude) as pickup_pt of type geometry
```

Comment: `CONCAT()` is a function that returns a text type as a result. If you want to combine 2 values (longitude and latitude) into a geometry type result, pick the appropriate function.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I go from a PostgreSQL native point type to a PostGIS point?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/156947/how-do-i-go-from-a-postgresql-native-point-type-to-a-postgis-point)

Answer (score 2):

## Can you cast? No.

`geometry` and `geography` are PostGIS types, and your types are likely `float`, `double`, or something like that.

## Can you create PostGIS types? Yes.

What you want to do is use [`ST_MakePoint(long,lat)`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html).

```
SELECT *, 
   ST_MakePoint(pickup_longitude, pickup_latitude) as pickup_pt, 
   ST_MakePoint(dropoff_longitude, dropoff_latitude) as dropoff_pt
```

## If you don't have PostGIS.

1. Get it. Install it. Use it: `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`
2. Or, if you can't get or have a *good* reason for not wanting it, then and only then should you even consider using the native type, `point`.

   ```
   SELECT *, 
      point(pickup_longitude, pickup_latitude) as pickup_pt, 
      point(dropoff_longitude, dropoff_latitude) as dropoff_pt
   ```

## Geometery vs Geography

Geography to geometry conversions are a function to PostGIS. But you can do it with

```
SELECT ST_MakePoint(long,lat)::geography;
```

Or, you can use another geometery srid with

```
SELECT ST_SetSRID( ST_MakePoint(long,lat), srid );
```